# ionic yii2 Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Tags: header, ionic-framework, yii2, cors

I have a Ionic App and I'm trying to do a POST:

```
$http({
  url: url+'/usuario/log', 
  method: 'POST',
  data: {usuario : $scope.data.usuario, senha:$scope.data.senha},
  headers : {'content-type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
}).then(function(result) { ... });
```

On the server side I have a Yii2 application:

```
public function actionLog(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type");

    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    $usuario = $params['usuario'];
    $senha = $params['senha'];

    ...
}
```

But the error I got is always this, I send a POST and get a OPTIONS

```
OPTIONS http://www.nexusolucoes.com.br/personal/web/usuario/log
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.nexusolucoes.com.br/personal/web/usuario/log. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with CORS, if the backend is on a different domain than the frontend the browser will always send an OPTIONS request first, to confirm that the cross domain sharing is allowed for the frontend domain.

If the browser gets a proper response for the OPTIONS, then, the POST request (the one you want) will be triggered as usual.

To sum up, you need to: Add a mapping on the URL Manager to respond to the OPTIONS verb for the exact same URL where you're sending the POST. Then, you need to create an action within a controller or to use the Yii's yii\rest\OptionsAction along with the CORS filters to allow the frontend domain to make the POST request.

Please check the following links for more information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-cors.html
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html